# Highlight record in Datagrid through quick search

Tags: datagrid, vb6, ado

I want to highlight a particular record in a `datagrid` when the record has been searched. it is like a quick search, the user writes the name and the record is instantly found. so far i only have an arrow pointing at the record but i need it to be highlighted completely. Images are provided for further explanation.
Code:

```
Private Sub txtQuickSearch_Change()
Dim varBookmark As Variant
        With StudentTable
                varBookmark = .Bookmark
            If (.SelBookmarks.Count <> 0) Then
                .SelBookmarks.Remove 0
            End If
                Adodc1.Recordset.MoveFirst

                Adodc1.Recordset.Find "[Last Name] like '" & txtQuickSearch.Text & "'"

            If frmStudents.Adodc1.Recordset.BOF Then

                .SelBookmarks.Add Adodc1.Recordset.Bookmark     
            End If
        End With
End Sub
```

[image: This is how it is now]

[image: This is how i would like it]

Comment: I think you want  `If Not frmStudents.Adodc1.Recordset.BOF Then`

Comment: when I do that it gives me this error `Run-time error '3021': Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.` @JimHewitt

Comment: `If Not frmStudents.Adodc1.Recordset.BOF And Not frmStudents.Adodc1.Recordset.EOF Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jim Hewitt, fixed the problem, I needed to add this statement:
    `If Not frmStudents.Adodc1.Recordset.BOF And Not frmStudents.Adodc1.Recordset.EOF Then`